# Plotly basic table not showing in web2py

Tags: python, plotly, web2py, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I have an issue regarding wep2py and the plotly library. I am trying to display a basic plotly table in web2py. I have made the table in my python controller with the plotly library:

```
def test_table():
    fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Table(header=dict(values=['A Scores', 'B Scores']),
                                   cells=dict(values=[[100, 90, 80, 90], [95, 85, 75, 95]]))
                          ])
    return fig.show()
    # fig.show() gives the same result
```

According to the [plotly docs](https://plot.ly/python/table/), this should be enough code to show the figure. I did put it in a function but I don't think should be a problem.

But when I pass this function to the front-end using a parameter, my browser tries to open a new tab, and the result on the tab where my web2py is running shows simply "None".

Answer (score 0):

Doing `return fig.show()` gives the problem.`fig.show()` does opens a plot in the browser when you run the code on your computer but it returns `None` so it won't work on the server.

I suggest saving a static HTML file that you can then serve or you can have your function to return `html` string. I hope it helps

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.offline import plot

fig1 = go.Figure(data=[{'type': 'bar', 'y': [1, 3, 2]}],
                        layout={'height': 400})

fig2 = go.Figure(data = [go.Table(header=dict(values=['A Scores', 'B Scores']),
                                  cells=dict(values=[[100, 90, 80, 90], [95, 85, 75, 95]]))])

div1 = plot(fig1, output_type='div', include_plotlyjs=False)
div2 = plot(fig2, output_type='div', include_plotlyjs=False)

html = """\
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        {div1}
        {div2}
    </body>
</html>
""".format(div1=div1, div2=div2)

with open('multi_plot.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(html)
```

[image]

Comment: Hmm, but then the interactiveness of the charts gets lost. That is the most important thing for me to have haha. I will try it out though!

Comment: Sorry, but you didn't mention anything about interactiveness in your question. You wrote letterly: "I am trying to display a **basic** Plotly table"

Comment: That is correct, because the first step usually is making it work. So if it does not work accordingly with some basic example, there is no need to try it out with a more difficult example... Next time I'll be more precise then!

Comment: I think that having an interactive Dash app boils down to starting a Dash app on the server (or have it running on other computer) and then redirecting to that address where the app runs (same server or other computer) Eventually the interactive communication is between the client (browser) and the computer running the "Dash server" using a specific port like 8050 or smth. So the WSGI server can be just redirecting to an URL where the Dash app runs and plays a role only at the beginning of what seems "serving the plot" (optionally starting the Dash server app itself).